# Unable to cast object of type XXXXXX to type IXXXXX (.NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, reflection

Can someone please explain what is happening to me? I have a test project that tests a dummy instance of my service. In the test project, I simply reference the dummyService.exe and System.SystemProcess dll.

In my dummyService project however, I have referenced the class library, which itself uses other dlls from other componentsn as well as other projects in my solution.

The problem is that when I run my test, exceptions get thrown( First Chance exceptions for dlls which are loaded and working in the dummyService), in addition invalidcast exception (error message below).

**Unable to cast object of type 'Export.CaseOutputGenerator' to type 'Export.ICaseOutputGenerator'.
System.InvalidCastException was caught
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Export.CaseOutputProcess.CustomCaseOutputGenerator' to type 
'Export.CaseOutputProcess.ICaseOutputGenerator'.
  Source=Export.CaseOutputProcess
  StackTrace:
       at Export.CaseOutputProcess.CaseOutputGeneratoryFactory.GetCaseOutputGeneratorObject(String assemblyName, String className) 
in C:\Monitor\Export.CaseOutputProcess\CaseOutputGeneratoryFactory.cs:line 56
at Monitor.BOMock.GenerateCaseOutput(String OutputFolder, String iFile, Int32 seqNum, DataTable CaseSettings, String SettingFileName) 
in C:\Monitor\BOMock\BOMock.cs:line 1069
at Monitor.BOMock.Handling() in C:\Monitor\BOMock\BOMock.cs:line 492 InnerException:**

```
     public static ICaseOutputGenerator GetCaseOutputGeneratorObject(string assemblyName, string className)
            {
                ICaseOutputGenerator customeOutputGen = null;

                var obj = GetObject(assemblyName, className);
                if (obj != null)
                    caseOutputGen = (ICaseOutputGenerator)obj; // FAILS HERE
                return caseOutputGen;
            }

   private static object GetObject(string fullName, string className)
        {
            try
            {
                Type caseOutputGen = null;
                var localAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullName);
                foreach (var testType in localAssembly.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (!testType.FullName.EndsWith(className, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) continue;
                    caseOutputGen = testType;
                    break;
                }
                if (caseOutputGen == null) return null;

                var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(caseOutputGen);
                return obj;
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to load assembly: " + Environment.NewLine + fullName, ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to load assembly: " + Environment.NewLine + fullName, ex);
            }
        }
```

Where assemblyName is the Path to the dll file to load and className happens to be the name of the class to create an instance of.

In the code, as you see, using reflection I load the assembly at the assemblyName PATH provided (String assemblyName) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx , and then using reflection again, I then create an instance of the className (String className ) contained in the loaded assembly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

How do I remedy this problem please? I don't want to have to reference all my dlls in the test project. How do I get around or solve this problem please?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked into Ninject for dependancy injection?

Comment: What is the *full* message? This *usually* happens when you have declared `ICaseOutputGenerator` in two different assemblies - in which case that is two different and unrelated `ICaseOutputGenerator` interfaces.

Comment: That happens to be the full message. I am not sure what other information I should post on this. Please let me know what exactly you need for me to post.

Comment: Does `CaseOutputGenerator` implement the `ICaseOutputGenerator` interface?

Comment: Yes it does implement it.

Comment: What does `GetObject` do?  How is it loading the class?  Is it leveraging a custom app domain?

Comment: It Loads the specified assembly. and then goes to create an instance of the className

Answer (score 0):

Based on that stack trace, it looks like the assembly where the type lives is not being found. If you just add the reference to the compiled exe, you're probably not going to get the other libraries along with it.  I think you've got a couple of choices:

1. Go ahead and bite the bullet: add the references to the other libraries in your test project.  They're typically not transitive: just because your service knows about them doesn't necessarily follow that your test's assembly knows about them as well.
2. Add a post-compilation step to your test's project that copies over the other assemblies so that they can be found by the app domain running your test.
3. Use dependency injection and an inversion of control container.  There are quite a few out there, but Castle Windsor, StructureMap and Unity come to mind.  Scott Hanselman's got a great list of them on his blog: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx

Comment: I have been testing these same, before this, quite successfully without doing any of what you suggest there. I am trying to test the service, and does it not make sense that the test, will let the service run it's show without needing to know all that goes on inside of it?

Comment: Possibly.  I think that really depends on what your test is actually doing, and whether the reference to the service's executable is copying that executable into your test assembly's folder without also copying across the executable's dependencies.

Comment: Looks like you're using a mocking library.  Is it possible the mocking library has trouble with statics?

Comment: I use reflection to load the assembly at the assemblyName path  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx , and then using reflection again, I create an instance of the className contained in the loaded assembly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

Comment: Anyone able to help me understand exactly why using reflection in my code would now require I add a reference to the reflected assembly to my test project?